# How to give path to files in plugins folder?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, paths

How to give path to enqueue in functions.php

---

wp-content/plugins/dl-grid-addons/includes/wp-bakery/tsw/tsw-tools/assets/js/tsw-tools.js

Answer (score -1):

I'd create a function and then use the wp_enqueue_scripts action to add your script to the list;

```
function load_more_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'tsw-tools-js', // unique handle name
    '/wp-content/plugins/dl-grid-addons/includes/wp-bakery/tsw/tsw-tools/assets/js/tsw-tools.js' // path relative to WordPress root directory
);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_more_scripts');
```

More information can be found here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/